# Input text value must be start with W,T or Z other character will not Work on keyboard as a first character

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Requirement is basically enter a text which Start with 'W','T' or 'Z' and then after we can insert any character or number. I have to use this on Keypress event if we press any key (Except W,T or Z) while entering text in field. The pressed key should not be visible on textbox.

For Example I am using following Script for mobile number validation :

$("[id$=InputTxt]").live('keypress', function(e) {
        return (e.which !=8 && e.which !=0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) ? false : true;
    });

Comment: You can use regular expression to get this

Comment: `live()` was also deprecated a *long* time ago. You should update the version of jQuery you include in the page and use `on()` instead

Comment: `"Walue".match(/^[WTZ]/)`

Comment: You writed *prevent string start with W,T,Z* in title but in text writed *press any key except W,T,Z*?

Comment: check my solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously not the shortest solution, but it's **easy to read and adopt**, as you can easily update the `allowedCharacters` in natural language, without fiddling around with keyCodes.

```
$("#customFormat").on("keypress", function(e) {
  var currentValue = $(this).val();
  var allowedCharacters = ['W', 'T', 'Z'];
  var newCharacter = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)

  if (currentValue != "" || allowedCharacters.indexOf(newCharacter) > -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ae64skr/1/

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roonie007/57j8gody/)

```
$("input").on("keypress",function(e)
{
    if(".116.119.122".indexOf(e.keyCode+"") == -1 && $("input").val().length <= 0)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain your code?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah there is nothing to explain , the 116 119 122 are the keycode of t w z if they are not pressed while the input length contains nothing , it will prevent the keypress

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sj9u7wk/1/)

```
$("#my_input").on('keydown',function (e) {
    return ([84, 87, 90].indexOf(e.which) > -1 || $(this).val().length > 0); 
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I can input values starting with W, T and Z.